# Развертывание собственных приложений C# на предприятии

Tags: c#, erp

Вопрос по теории. Развертывание и сопровождение программ на предприятии написанных на C#.

Немного о прошлом.

Начинал я свой путь программиста с Delphi на одном предприятии. В середине 90ыx.  Достаточно крупном, на  1.5к сотрудников.  Отдел IT был небольшой. 4-5 человек. И мы писали свою систему на Delphi от принятия заказа до выдачи со склада. Плюс сопровождающие программы расчета ЗП. Автоматизация отдела кадров. Планирование производства и т д. 200+пользователей онлайн. В общем, работы было много и интересно. Каждое приложение это отдельный exe модуль. Было их штук 7 или 8….  Был написан лаунчер который проверял актуальность версии и обновлял основную программу при запуске.  Так как разработка велась постоянно. Программа могла обновляться по несколько раз в день. Даже если меняли что-то незначительно, обновить exe модули на локальных машинах  приходилось.  Все это прекрасно работало почти 10 лет. Частично писалось и на C#. Delphi умирал как язык. И чтобы идти в ногу со временем переходили на C#. Все так же работало через лаунчер. Я работал на одном заводе. И его обслуживал. Предприятие выросло для нескольких заводов, и задумались о приобретении Серьезной ERP системы. Был куплен ERP SAP R/3. И пошло внедрение. Все работает. В SAP системе там все удобней для разработки. Есть сервер разработки. Транспорт на продуктив. Если мелкая правка она на продуктив вообще влетает незаметно для пользователя. А мелкая правка на C# приведет к перезапуску exe модуля. Если сложная правка с изменениями таблиц, то делается обновление утром пока никого нет. Гемор с exe модулями как бы отсутствует. Ну и я уже лет 15 абапер.  Возможно, в силу ряда причин придется вернуться к разработке на C#.  Посему вопрос: А как сейчас сделать подобную систему, чтобы не морочиться с exe модулями?  И как обновлять пользователю программу локально. Максимально для него удобно? Я напишу опять лаунчер(свой steam) и т д. Будет работать. Но может, есть способ проще? После сапа отстал я немного от технологий.
Надо учитывать следующее: Разработка будет идти в реальном времени. Есть сложные моменты, и придется обновляться по несколько раз в день. Если найдена критическая ошибка нужно исправить… срочно.
Сделать свой внутренний язык  и компилиться при изменениях это сложновато, не та группа разработчиков. 1-2 человека.   Это будет Winforms приложения. Web не предлагать. То что нужно на Web уже реализовано на WEB.Свести к минимум обновления на начальном этапе будет сложно. Так как группа небольшая. Много расчетов. Работать уже надо но ошибки править по ходу обнаружения. В общем давайте исходить из того что нужно написать программу на C# и будут работать 20 пользователей. Задача максимально просто производить обновления exe модулей.
Пока в мыслях написать свой мини steam :-)
Ваши предложения?
Спасибо.

Comment: Если нужно часто обновлять без перезапуска приложения, то можно попробовать динамическую подгрузку DLL-модулей.

Comment: `Немного о прошлом` И пожалуйста, не нужно расписывать разные истории, тут не читальный клуб, пишите только по делу.

Comment: `Немного о прошлом` А мне понравилось) Здоро было отвлечься и немного почитать историй, да и написано захватывающе. Но лучше, действительно, концентрироваться на проблеме.

Comment: есть много опций. OneClick, свой лаунчер, [магазин приложений предприятия](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/deploy-modern-applications). Если вам надо обновлять сборки без перезагрузки (что, по моему, лютый геморрой), то тут скорее всего свой лаунчер только спасет.

Comment: С другой стороны, вы бы добавили инфу, что вы такого делаете в дестопе, что нельзя сделать через веб? Что вам мешает сделать фронтенд тогда на десктопе, а всю логику держать в вебе? Генерация языка  - задача несложная (см [antlr](https://www.antlr.org/)), но вы не пояснили ничего в вопросе, вы пришли с задачей, а не с проблемой, потому вам что то, что бы конкретно вам подходило, очень сложно посоветовать.

Comment: Под WinForms я бы все таки остановился на ClickOnce, ну как минимум для начала. Да, у него есть свои заморочки, но для пользователя все прозрачно, обновления проверяются при запуске приложения автоматически (при соответствующей настройке), ни каких дополнительных инструментов кроме VS не требуется. Когда потребуется что-то большее, тогда можно будет думать о собственном лаунчере, динамическом связывании dll и прочих хитрых штуках, сложность доведения до ума которых часто не компенсируется полученным эффектом. Решать вам, однозначного ответа на ваш вопрос нет.

Comment: Спасибо отвечающим. Всетаки пока прихожу к выводу свой "стим". Посмотрю что такое Click Once. Не сталкивался с ним.

Comment: Еще можно написать либу-обновлятор, и прикрутить ее к каждому приложению, чтобы оно само себя обновляло. Скайнет (распределенная система) лучше справится с такой задачей. Вот если бы вам надо было обновлять приложения, разработанные не вами, тогда "стим" - единственный выход.

Comment: "чтобы не морочиться с exe модулями", "Web не предлагать" - ну тогда только как предлагал Геннадий П (подгрузку DLL-модулей), вот только как их отключать - уже другой вопрос... Так или иначе нужно будет перезапускать приложение. Можно конечно посмотреть в сторону динамической компиляции и рефлексии и пусть клиентские приложения получают этот код, тогда не будет заморочек с модуль-файлами, но сама система будет сложнее. Не представляю как это должно разрабатываться 1-2 людьми, да ещё и по выпуску нескольких патчей в день...